# Animated UIImageView and UITableView on viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, uiimageview

I have one `UIViewController` with my logo centered and `UITableView` with alpha 0.

In `viewDidAppear:` I have this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [self.logo setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.size.height - 194.0f, 320.0f, 194.0f)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.table setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, self.view.frame.size.height - 194.0f)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [self.table setAlpha:1.0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        return;
    }];

    return;
}];
```

Ok, the animation is what I want.

But when I call `presentModalViewController:` to show next view, `UIImageView` back to center of screen and `UITableView` back the the height before.

How do I stay with the same size and position after finishing the animation even change the view?

Thanks.

Comment: When do you see them go back? After you dismiss the modal view controller or as it's showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you set your original frames in `viewDidLoad` this is fine unless the modal clears your system memory. Views are cached as long as they can. So if you modal uses enough memory to reset it, `viewDidLoad` gets called again resetting your view.

A quick and easy way to deal with this is to set the values you want in the `dismissViewController:animated:` method if you're using it, or a delegate method for the modal.

If you don't have either of those you'll need to do some checking somehow if this is the first load. This isn't a clean way to deal with it though. If you show some more code we may be able to work out a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note: you're using the wrong options constant. Rather than `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut`, should be using `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`. That probably doesn't affect your problem, but it is bad.

Also, you don't need `return` statements in your completion blocks.

I would check the code in your viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear methods. It's possible you're doing initial layout in there (or even in layoutSubviews) which is resetting the view.